# std::function vs alias function pointer , why one wont compile

Tags: c++

Wanting to investigate the performance hit (if any) of `std:function`.

I have this struct:

```
struct InstructionDescription
{
    std::string name;
    word mask;
    word code;
    std::function<void(Cpu*, word)> func;
    word flags;
};
```

and I set up a vector of them like this

```
std::vector<InstructionDescription> instructions_{
{
    {"clr",     DD_MASK,        0005000,    &Cpu::Clr},
    {"clrb",    DD_MASK,        0105000,    &Cpu::Clr},
    {"com",     DD_MASK,        0005100,    &Cpu::Com},

.....
```

Works fine. Now if I change the struct to use a function pointer:

```
using InstrFunc = void(*)(Cpu*, word);
struct InstructionDescription
{
    std::string name;
    word mask;
    word code;
    InstrFunc func;
    word flags;
};
```

which as far as I can see should be equivalent. And yet I get

```
1>C:\work\pdp\mysim\mysim\instructions.h(60,50): error C2664: 'std::vector<Cpu::InstructionDescription,std::allocator<Cpu::InstructionDescription>>::vector(std::initializer_list<_Ty>,const _Alloc &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'initializer list' to 'std::initializer_list<_Ty>'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=Cpu::InstructionDescription,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<Cpu::InstructionDescription>
1>        ]
1>        and
1>        [
1>            _Ty=Cpu::InstructionDescription
1>        ]
1>C:\work\pdp\mysim\mysim\instructions.h(60,50): message : Element '1': no conversion from 'initializer list' to '_Ty'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=Cpu::InstructionDescription
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include\vector(512,5): message : see declaration of 'std::vector<Cpu::InstructionDescription,std::allocator<Cpu::InstructionDescription>>::vector'
1>Console.cpp
```

VS2019. VS GUI is also highlighting the std::vector line saying 'InstructionDescription' is unknown and that the function names are not accessible (&Cpu::Clr for example)

The `Cpu` class is defined like:

```
struct Cpu {
    void Clr(word) {}; 
    void Com(word) {}; 
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please make a [mre]. We can't reproduce the error with the provided code.

Comment: See https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `std::function` is very convenient: it recognizes that `&Cpu::Clr` is a member function whose first parameter will be a `Cpu*`.

When you make it a function pointer, this doesn't work like this.  You have to use a member function pointer:

```
using InstrFunc = void (Cpu::*)(word);
```

### Additional info

This is standard: `std::function` nicely copes with pointers to member functions by adding a pointer to the class as first argument.  Of course, when you call it, you have to provide that additional parameter:

```
Cpu cpu;  
for (auto& i:instructions_) {
    i.func(&cpu, i.code);   // as simple as that with std::function
}
```

When you go for the pointer to member function, it's less convenient:

```
Cpu cpu;  
for (auto& i:instructions) {
    (cpu.*i.func)(i.code); 
}
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/6KbZkj) (you need to comment/ comment out the specific lines)

Comment: Is that standard? That `std::function` will accept a member function and convert it to the equivalent regular function?

Comment: @john it gets half way there, you have to tell std::function that the func takes a Cpu* as first parameter and pass it a 'this' when invoking

Comment: that compiles - ty, but whats the syntax to invoke the function. I had idesc.func(this, inst) but thats not right.

Comment: @john I've edited to address this point and provide a demo that you can play with.

Comment: @pm100 calling a pointer to member function is much less flexible.  I've edited to show how to do

Comment: ty v much.. BTW - huge perf difference in debug build, I assume release build optimize both cases to the same thing